# Microsoft bing translator, API REQUEST LIMIT

Tags: microsoft-translator

In Microsoft document mentioned, Each Translate request is limited to 5,000 characters.

In the free plan, we are able to send 5000 characters in one request.

Is it possible to request unlimit characters in one request.

Comment: this is not possible.

Comment: Hi @Fai The Translator API says our credentials are invalid even though we're using `Key 1` from our `Keys and Endpoints` page. We're just trying the tutorials from here, and it keeps failing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-reference. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: From what you've said, I would guess your key is invalid :) How are you specifying auth?